# convert list of lists to a list of smaller tuples

Tags: python

I need some help with converting a list of equal sized lists `x` to a list of tuples such that each tuple should be the length of `x`

```
x = [
['4', '8', '16', '32', '64', '128', '256', '512', '1,024'], 
['1,200', '2,400', '4,800', '4,800', '6,200', '6,200', '6,200', '6,200', '6,200'], 
['300', '600', '1,200', '2,400', '3,200', '3,200', '4,000', '4,000', '4,000']
]
# some functions that converts it to 
expected_output = [('4', '1,200', '300'), ('8', '2,400', '600'), ...]
```

in this case `len(x)` is 3 but I want a function that can handle any length of x

Comment: What should happen if you want len to be 3 but encounter sublist of length 7 i.e. not evenly divisble?

Comment: @Daweo the lists inside x will always be of equal length, so if `len(x)` is 7 the tuple size will be 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip` with unpacking operator `*`:

```
out = list(zip(*x))
```

Output:

```
[('4', '1,200', '300'),
 ('8', '2,400', '600'),
 ('16', '4,800', '1,200'),
 ('32', '4,800', '2,400'),
 ('64', '6,200', '3,200'),
 ('128', '6,200', '3,200'),
 ('256', '6,200', '4,000'),
 ('512', '6,200', '4,000'),
 ('1,024', '6,200', '4,000')]
```

Comment: works perfectly, Can I ask what does the *x exactly do and when is it useful?

Comment: @User19 `x` is a list of lists and `*` allows us to unpack them as `len(x)` separate lists.

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution:

```py
list(zip(*x))
```

Comment: Can you make it dynamic? this only works if length of x is 3